# CryptoJS key generator

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I have a reference to CryptoJS v3.1.2 and when trying the following javascript code:

```
var txtpassword = document.getElementById("myPassword").value.trim();
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
var key256Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(txtpassword, salt, { keySize: 256 / 32 });
```

It blows up on PBKDF2, proclaiming "Object doesn't support property or method 'PBKDF2'".  I see many references online to calling PBKDF2 like this, what am I missing?

Comment: If possible, please provide a link to these 'many references online'.

Comment: Here's one: https://github.com/xdumaine/crypto-js/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

I was missing all the rest of the associated js files.  I was able to download the complete library from here

https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Including this CDN fixed the reference error on my end: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>`